# Node-Schedule run on different processes

Tags: node.js

I'm using [node-schedule](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule) for doing cron job with nodejs. This is my code:

```
import '../config';
import schedule from 'node-schedule';

import { startAssignment, closeAssignment } from '../course/schedule';

schedule.scheduleJob('*/1 * * * *', startAssignment);
schedule.scheduleJob('*/1 * * * *', closeAssignment);
```

I wonder if two scheduled jobs run on different processes or the same? I try to view on Linux using

> sudo ps -aux

and it give this:

> 22032  0.0  0.0   4632   864 pts/2    S+   17:47   0:00 /bin/sh -c
> NODE_PATH=. babel-node app/schedule/index.js

which mean it is running on the same process. So is there any way to make them run on **different process with different pid**?

Why I need them to run on diffeent **processes** with different **pids**? Because when a process start, I want to check if there is a similar process running with the same **pid**, so I stop them to prevent **duplicate processes** which may take too much resource of the server.

Thank you. I appreciate any type of documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a fork for multiple processes in the node.

```
const { fork } = require('child_process');
```

https://itnext.io/multi-threading-and-multi-process-in-node-js-ffa5bb5cde98

Comment: So I have to schedule a job, then in my function, I will fork a child_process?

Comment: does it return a pid or something like that?